# change right position depending on class css

Tags: html, css

I have a button that I want to use as a tab on a side bar to start I want it at

```
 right: 0;
 position: absolute;
```

but then when it has the class btnactive I want it to be 320px from the right so

```
 right: 320px;
 position: absolute;
```

should work but the button just goes missing off the page, kind of a simple question cant figure it out thanks a lot

or if anyone knows another way..

I have a button that I want to the left of a sidebar that I toggle in and out thats 320px wide

[image]

Comment: You are missing a semi-colon after px. Other than that, try a negative number and see what that does.

Comment: Its not the semi-colon I just used that as an example, using a negative number doesnt do anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after playing around for a while in the dev tools, floating right and then putting a margin-left 320px works perfectly

so the code is like this

```
.sidebar-closed{
    float: right;
}

.sidebar-open{
   margin-right: 320px;
}
```